# Normalisation into BCNF

Tags: database, relational-database, relation

I have a relation looks like:

```
R = (X,Y,C,D)
```

and functional dependencies:

```
FD = {XY -> CD, YC -> D, D -> X}
```

I found out that the candidate keys are XY, YC, YD.

In this case, I have 3 candidate keys... so how do I use them when I decompose the relation into BCNF? I've never done decomposition of the relation with more than one key...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Relation 1: (Y,C,D)
Relation 2: (D,X)

Answer (score 0):

@KeyM

**1.Find out the FD that violates BCNF**

In this case its D->X

**2.Decompose into two relations R1,R2**

R1(D,X)  R2(D,rest)

**3. Repeat 1,2 until all of the  relations are in BCNF**

Using this our solution is R1(Y,C,D) , R2(D,X)